# What is the best way to emulate `around_filter` when using Grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

I want to set the timezone for each request that my app receive, with an `application_controller.rb` I did this:

```
around_filter :user_time_zone, :if => :current_user

def user_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
end
```

But I am having difficult to find an equivalent that suites my current application that uses the `Grape` gem.

The only thing I have found seems to be [this](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/intridea/grape/Grape/Middleware/Filter):

```
use Grape::Middleware::Filter, before: lambda {  Time.zone current_user.time_zone }, after: lambda { Time.zone 'UTC' }
```

But I would like to know if there is something cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You could put that common behaviour in a module.

Here's how I did something similar:

```
module API
  module V1
    module Defaults
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      included do
        helpers do
          def current_user
            # ...
          end
        end

        before do
          Time.zone = current_user.timezone
        end

        after do
          Time.zone = Rails.configuration.time_zone
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

module API
  module V1
    class Things < Grape::API

      include API::V1::Defaults

    end
  end
end
```